# Basic surge and overvoltage protection

Tags: emc, surge-protection, tvs

My requirements are:

- protect the device from surges according to IEC 61000-4-5 Class 2
- protect from 400VAC long term overvoltage (working voltage is 220VAC-15%...230VAC+10%)

IEC 61000-4-5 Class 2:

[image]

(from [this](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00080038.pdf) document)

The very first thought was to place a series current limiting resistor and TVS diode:

[image]

According to my simulation this working fine: voltage limiting at acceptable level. But there are several drawbacks:

- My device is measuring AC voltage so the current, consumed by the schematic will change the measures. My estimation is that everything above 10K will have significant influence on a measure.
- Both TVS and resistor will be pretty hot at 400 VAC (my calculation is that even at 50K power will be about 800 mW). The lower current limiting resistor resistance - the higher temperature but lower measuring interference.

Next I thought of PTC resistor in 50K place. This should be perfect for my case but they are appeared to be rare and expensive. All I was able to find is Vishay's [TFPT series](http://www.vishay.com/docs/33017/tfpt.pdf) which will have only 33% more Ohms at 100 C. Definitely not enough.

So I look at the cheap solution. May be I missed a solution worth consideration?

Comment: what comes after phase_r? Maybe the key to protecting the device lies there. In regard to power dissipation: you might be able to use a capacitor instead of a resistor.

Comment: @Christian, thank you for your input! Could you make clear what you've meant saying "key"? I have a MOSFET dropping down the voltage and LP2980 after all. Regarding the capacitor: you've meant to put one in series? But 400VAC cap with needed capacitance will be huge (for my application even extra 1206 component is "big") and probably expensive. Moreover I think it will destroy the possibility to measure the mains.

Comment: do you only measure the AC voltage or are you also supplying your device from it. "Key" as in "the solution to your problem"

Comment: Yes, @Christian, I do both: supply my circuit and I measure AC mains voltage. And I still not getting into the 'key'. Sorry for being so slowminded :)